# Mouse not working on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, mouse, wireless-mouse

Previously my mouse was working fine on Ubuntu 10.04.

Now, starting today, it stopped working. I tested with 2 other mice, but it's still not working. The mouse is turning on though, I see the lights on the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

The mouse getting lit up means there's power, but not necessarily that you have communication with the system.

I'd probably start by checking if X actually detects the mouse with `xinput list` and checking if mouse input is detected by using `evtest` - if either of these fails, the issue might be lower level, possibly to do with evdev.

If both of these work, this might be x config related - maybe create a backup for your xorg.conf file if you have one, and create a generic one with `sudo Xorg -configure` (or just make sure there isn't one, like with newer ubuntu versions)

It might also help if you knew what exactly happened before it stopped working.

You might get some ideas as to what else to poke at from [Ubuntu's X input config page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input)